# Skype - voice fine, but no notification sounds

Tags: 11.04, sound, pulseaudio, skype

I have Skype installed via Software Center on clean copy of Ubuntu 11.04. Skype package version is `2.2.0.25-1maverick1`. Voice calls work perfectly fine both ways. But notification sounds do not work at all, which is weird since they use exactly the same audio device.

On the screen below, if I click `Make a test call` it works fine. If I click `Make a test sound` I hear nothing at all.

[image: Skype settings]

Hardware is 2010 MBP 13" (7,1) with nVidia soundcard.

```
00:08.0 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP89 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
```

Comment: additional information about your hardware and versions ect.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have "Warning sounds" in your audio preferences muted?
Uncheck "Stumm", dont know the english layout of the dialog :)

edit: this is the `System Preferences -> Sound options` dialog. 
[image]

Comment: Actually not muted, but somewhere at 10%. BTW. Please add to your answer, that this is `System Preferences` -> `Sound options` dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.10...Same issue... Solved this way

Go to System Settings -> Under Hardware heading, select Sound app ->  Click on the Sound Effects tab  -> Make sure that you have specified a sufficient volume level using the "Alert Volume..." slider